# How do a I terminate a co.js loop after execution?

Tags: co

Whenever I run a co generator loop, nothing happens after execution the process just hangs. How do I terminate after completion?

```
co(function *() {
    // code;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Co()` returns a promise. Simply return from the loop and handle it with `.then()`. Here we return the string `"done"`, send that to `console.log`, and terminate the process. Any errors will be printed to the console.

```
co(function *() {
    return "done";
}).then(
  res => { console.log(res); process.exit() }
).catch(err => console.error(err) );
```